# Show question/input in vscode jupyter notebook output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Is there any way to show input question in cell output while using vscode jupyter notebook?
When I use Google Colab, there are question in the cell output. I want to know how to show question without using print().

In google Colab: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L71OS.png

In vsCode: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4szQJ.png

Answer (score 8):

At present, the Jupyter function in VSCode is provided by Python extension. The bottom of each cell is used to display output. Therefore, the input it receives is provided by the input box above, which is its display input mode.

[image]

If you want to display input and output in the same place, it is recommended that you use a python file, and the terminal will display the input and output content in turn.

[image]

Comment: So is there are no way to disable input box in VSCode Jupyter?

Comment: @hojin3777 -Yes, currently, the input of Jupyter in VSCode is here and here is the integrated design. This is an important input channel, we better not disable it.

Answer (score 0):

## You may substitute builtins input by your own function

```
import builtins
def input(prompt):
    x = builtins.input(prompt)
    print(prompt+x)
    return x
```

Comment: this example appears incomplete. It does nothing.