# Jupyter Notebook in VS Code : inline input()?

Tags: visual-studio-code, input, jupyter-notebook

I'm a student using VS Code to work on Jupyter Notebooks. I'm looking for a way to get the dialog pop up of an input("...") to appear inline instead (under the cell with all my prints, like it's done when using jupyter notebook in a browser).

Thanks,
Julien

Answer (score 2):

Found my answer here : [Show question/input in vscode jupyter notebook output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64350646/show-question-input-in-vscode-jupyter-notebook-output)

Spoiler : not possible, in VS Code you cannot show inputs under a cell of a jupyter notebook as it for output only.

Comment: Really? So we can use anaconda or google colab

Comment: Well if you use `input()` in VSCode, it will show an input dialog box but it will render as a popup at the top of your screen instead of right after your notebook's cell (like in Colab)