# How to view and enter Input prompt below the code cell in VS Code Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

VS Code does not shows the input given in the Jupyter Notebook, just the output. I want to save my Jupyter Notebooks with the input given also i.e. inline input, to improve readability.

[VS Code enter input prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0KQw.png)

[VS Code not showing what was given as input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhZxM.png)

The Jupyter Server does this, but I prefer VS Code for the aesthetic reasons and code completion and better integration with Git.

[Jupyter Notebook server also showing the input given,(What I want to have, unlike VS Code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rux5I.png)

Is there any way to also have the input provided below the code cell in VS Code?

I tried looking into the settings and can't find one addressing this.

I also referred to this link: [Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks)

A previous question regarding this( ~ 3 years ago): [Show question/input in vscode jupyter notebook output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66851727/jupyter-notebook-in-vs-code-inline-input)

Comment: why should it print the value of n unless you specifically ask it to with a `print(n)` statement ?  what you observe is just a feature of jupyter and i would argue that this is a spurious (and potentially annoying) print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct way to achieve this is with an explicit `print` statement as opposed to relying on the default behaviour of any given editor.

I would also argue that the behaviour of VScode is more consistent in the sense that i do not want to see a number unless i specifically request it with a print statement !

So this is what i would expect to do:

```py
n = int(input())
print(f'there are {n} stars.')

i = 1
while i <= n:
    spaces = 1
    while spaces <= n - i:
        print(' ', end='')
        spaces = spaces + 1
    stars = 1
    while stars <= i:
        print('*', end='')
        stars = stars + 1
    print()
    i += 1
```

And this is the output:

```
there are 4 stars.
   *
  **
 ***
****
```

having said this, the jupyter notebook in vscode does provision for the fact that the last variable in the cell is printed. so if you wanted to see the value of n, then you could make the last line of code `n`...

Comment: Agree! 
Now I can think of a situation where this would prove to be even more readable and won't create confusion in case of some output which has numbers.