# Python user input function is not working on Python version 3.9.7

Tags: python

```py
s = input("Enter user name:")  
print("The name of the user is", s)
```

I tried to run this code on Jupyter notebook in VS code but it did not show any options which usually takes input from user.

I tried running the same code on online python compiler and it worked perfectly. I don't know what's wrong.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What Error are you getting?

Comment: It could be some issues with Jupyter notebook, can you add a screenshot?

Comment: It works fine in jupyter, there must be something wrong with your environment. Do add your error or traceback for better understanding of your issue.

Comment: i did not get any errors

Comment: I think this is specific to vs code as this is running just fine in normal jupyter notebook.

Comment: Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64350646/show-question-input-in-vscode-jupyter-notebook-output) and other relevant answers, might help you with what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not know that in vs code editor, the input it receives is provided by the input box above, which is its display input mode.