# input() command issue in jupyter notebook and vs code interactive mode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, input, jupyter-notebook

I am running the following code in a jupyter noteboook or in vs code (interactive mode):

```
from IPython.display import clear_output

for i in range(5):
    print('This is a test!')
    a = input('Enter something: ')
    clear_output()
```

It is supposed to print the message first and then ask for the input. Sometimes it happens that the input is asked without the message being printed. In the next step of the loop the message is then printed twice.

NOTE: sometimes the above example works how it is supposed to (the number of repeats is small enough I guess). In my real world application I have a couple of hundreds of inputs to do and the above error pops up sooner or later.

I found this solution: [Show question/input in vscode jupyter notebook output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64350646/show-question-input-in-vscode-jupyter-notebook-output)

But I'd prefer the notebook environment.

Comment: I am afraid it's impossible. When you are using jupyter notebook or interactive, you are connected to a kernel server, both the input in the command palette or output on the notebook and interactive there is some delay.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steven. Your answer got me on the right track. I implemented a pause of 1 sec between printing the message and asking for input. Now it works.